# R Count instances of victory by group

Tags: r, summary

I have a dataframe 'df' where I want to summarize how many times each 'user' has a higher 'total' value for each head-to-head 'game'. My data frame looks like this:

| game | user | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L | 55 |
| 1 | J | 60 |
| 2 | L | 64 |
| 2 | J | 77 |
| 3 | L | 90 |
| 3 | J | 67 |
| 4 | L | 98 |
| 4 | J | 88 |
| 5 | L | 71 |
| 5 | J | 92 |

The summary would state that L had a higer total in 2 games and J had a higher total in 3 games.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming df is your dataframe the following should give you the long form summary.

```
df %>% 
  arrange(game,desc(total)) %>%  #we sort descending to ensure winner row is first.
  group_by(game) %>% # we group the rows per game, this allows for winner row to be first in each group
  slice_head(n=1)%>% #get first row in each group i.e winner row
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
   game user  total
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 J        60
2     2 J        77
3     3 L        90
4     4 L        98
5     5 J        92
```

If you just want the user wise summary add **count** to the code as follows:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(game,desc(total)) %>%  #we sort descending to ensure winner row is first.
  group_by(game) %>% # we group the rows per game, this allows for winner row to be first in each group
  slice_head(n=1) %>%  #get first row in each group i.e winner row
  ungroup() %>% 
  count(user)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  user      n
  <chr> <int>
1 J         3
2 L         2
```

Answer (score 2):

Same approach as Vinay, using data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[order(total), tail(.SD, 1), game][, .N, user]
#>      user     N
#>    <char> <int>
#> 1:      J     3
#> 2:      L     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Data used:

```r
df <- structure(list(game = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L
), user = c("L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J"), 
    total = c(55L, 60L, 64L, 77L, 90L, 67L, 98L, 88L, 71L, 92L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the type of output you want?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(game = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L),
                     user = c("L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J"), 
                     total = c(55L, 60L, 64L, 77L, 90L, 67L, 98L, 88L, 71L, 92L)
                     ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
df %>%
  group_by(game) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = total,
            n = 1,
            with_ties = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  summarise(wins = n())
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   user  wins
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 J         3
#> 2 L         2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

If you have a draw, then the above method counts that as a 'win' for both users. To count a draw as 'no winner' for both users (e.g. shown in game 1, below), you could use:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(game = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L),
                     user = c("L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J", "L", "J"), 
                     total = c(55L, 55L, 64L, 77L, 90L, 67L, 98L, 88L, 71L, 92L)
                     ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df
#>    game user total
#> 1     1    L    55
#> 2     1    J    55
#> 3     2    L    64
#> 4     2    J    77
#> 5     3    L    90
#> 6     3    J    67
#> 7     4    L    98
#> 8     4    J    88
#> 9     5    L    71
#> 10    5    J    92

df %>%
  group_by(game) %>%
  distinct(total, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n() >= 2) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = total,
            n = 1,
            with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  summarise(win = n())
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   user    win
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 J         2
#> 2 L         2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This answer seemed useful at first, but the summary gives two extra outcomes than total possible outcomes in my actual dataframe. Can you tell me more about the 'with_ties' portion?

Comment: If there is a draw both users 'win'; is that what you want? Or do both users 'not win' in that case? Or, like in @Vinay's solution, do you want to pick the user that comes first alphabetically if there is a tie?

Comment: Gotcha. I understand now. Thank you for taking the time to explain that. Does there another option to ignore ties altogether?

Comment: Yes, the second method in my answer ignores ties, i.e. if there is a draw, there is no winner

Answer (score 1):

We can group the data by game, `slice_max` and then `count` the resulting data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(game) %>%
    slice_max(total) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    count(user)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   user      n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 J         3
#> 2 L         2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that if there's a tie, it will add one to both teams:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- 
read_table('game    user    total
1   L   60
1   J   60
2   L   64
2   J   77
3   L   90
3   J   67
4   L   98
4   J   88
5   L   71
5   J   92')

df %>% group_by(game) %>%
    slice_max(total) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    count(user)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   user      n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 J         3
#> 2 L         3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>